# How to load third party libraries in karma.conf.js

Tags: karma-jasmine, karma-runner, onedrive

I am using OneDrive library file to launch OneDrive picker in my angular project. It works correctly in my application. But when i tried to test with Karma, i am getting error 'Cannot find variable OneDrive'.

So I have included reference karma.conf.js

```
files: [
   'http://js.live.net/v7.0/OneDrive.js'
],
```

After including library file getting error 'Error: [OneDriveSDK Error] object was missing and not optional in http://js.live.net/v7.0/OneDrive.js (line 2)'. Is there any way to resolve this issue?